# Cannot read property 'getCollectionByRoute' of undefined - Gutenberg wordpress

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, react-dom, wordpress-gutenberg

Gutenberg Editor In worpdress keep crashing from time ti time and i get the message "The editor has encountered an unexpected error".

When I open the console I get a React error that said:" Cannot read property 'getCollectionByRoute' of undefined".

Anyone have any idea what causes this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem as you, so I think it's something related to the post categories. So as a workaround to allow you editing your posts you can clean your site cookies and the next time you edit your post don't expand the categories section. If you need it then use the quick edit.